# Get Long value from Long Array exception in Java

Tags: java

I want to try to get `Long` value from Long Array. But I've got this exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Code like this :

```
import java.util.List;        
    public class Bar {        
        private List<Long> departments;      

        public List<Long> getDepartments() {
            return departments;
        }     

        public void setDepartments(List<Long> departments) {
            this.departments = departments;
        }           

    }


import java.util.List;    
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;    
public class Foo {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        String str = "{\"departments\":[20,22]}";
        JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject.fromObject(str);
        Bar bar = (Bar) jsonObject.toBean(jsonObject, Bar.class);
        List<Long> departments = bar.getDepartments();
        Long depId = departments.get(0);// Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
System.out.println(depId);

    }    
}
```

Comment: Probably because jsonObject.toBean injects at runtime a List of Integer instead of Long

Comment: Try `JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("department"); Collection<Long> depts = JSONArray.toCollection(jsonArray, List.class);` if  it helps. Haven't tried myself. Here is the JavaDoc of the `toCollection()` method: **Returns a List or a Set taking generics into account.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "{\"departments\":[20,22]}";
    JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject.fromObject(str);
    Bar bar =  (Bar) JSONObject.toBean(jsonObject, Bar.class);
    List departments = bar.getDepartments();
    Long i=  Long.valueOf(departments.get(0).toString());
    System.out.println(i);
    System.out.println(departments.get(0).getClass().getName());

}
```

It's a net.sf json cast bug, just cast to string

Comment: You can  use jackson to void json cast  exception

Comment: Can not cast to string. Trying to String s = departments.get(0).toString(); throws same exception.

Comment: ```public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "{\"departments\":[20l,22l]}";
    JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject.fromObject(str);
    Bar bar =  (Bar) JSONObject.toBean(jsonObject, Bar.class);
    List departments = bar.getDepartments();
      Long i=  Long.valueOf(departments.get(0).toString());
      System.out.println(i);
    System.out.println(departments.get(0).getClass().getName());

}

Comment: any class  could  to  string

Answer (score 0):

The you can try like this,

```
Long depId = (Long) departments.get(0).intValue();
```

Where [`intValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#intValue) returns int, but then you cast it to Long.

Comment: @MuammerTÜZÜN Can you show what `departments.get(0)` returns actually without storing it to any variables. Just by logging or printing it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Long depId = departments.get(0).longValue();
```

EDIT:

```
Integer i = 9;
Long l = i.longValue();
System.out.println(i + "  " + l);
```

Comment: did not work.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
 at com.test.Foo.main(Foo.java:16)

Comment: departments.get(0) method's return type is Long but its try to return Integer. This is the source of the problem.

Comment: if ``departments.get(0)`` return still a ``Integer`` it will be converted to ``Long`` by ``longValue()`` method. Plz check again and inform me.

Comment: @Md. muzahidul Islam Do not think in Java, this is a problem at bytecode level due to a bug in the toBean method.

Answer (score 0):

Long i=  Long.valueOf(departments.get(0).toString()); will solve your problem

Comment: Your code is working when; List departments = ... ; but i defined like this List<Long> departments = .. ; same error continues.

Answer (score 0):

The toBean() method produces a different Class with `List<Integer>`.
I do not see any reason to cast an Integer to Long due to this bug.
Change departments to `List<Integer>` or use an another JSon Parser.

Answer (score 0):

JSON itself has not notion of `Integer` or `Long`, it just know `Number`. A Number value - or a list of that - is put into an `Integer` object by JSONObject if it is not a floating pint value.

The fact that you declared the List as a `List<Long>`is not relevant for JSONObject, as this generic type information is not available in the compiled class code (type erasure), there `departments` is just a list of objects and so JSONObject happily fills in Integer objects.

You could either declare `departments`as `List<Integer>` or use additional transformation methods (have a look at ujulu's comment to your post)